# sql IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the sql below but can not get it to work

```
select product_category, 
       (
        select top 1 sub_category 
          from sub_categories 
         where product_category IN (keywords)
       ) as s 
  from products;
```

product category is Baby Gift Baskets and the keywords field is Baby Gift Baskets,Baby Gifts

basically want to get sub_category when product_category is found in the keywords list?

Comment: You have a multi-valued field, this is almost always a bad solution, as you've discovered. What if you want to search for "Baby" as a keyword? @Martin Smith's answer below is a better solution than the one you accepted as it deals with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use

```
where ',' + keywords + ',' like '%,'+ product_category + ',%'
```

this would be much easier and more efficient with a normalised database structure. (Your current structure with multiple keywords in a single column violates [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form))

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted one, it deals with keywords that can be part of larger keywords, ie. "Gifts" vs. "Baby Gifts".

Answer (score 0):

This will not work for you, as the `keywords` is seen as a single item.

You will have to split the values from keyword to be able to use an `IN`

Have a look at

[Split Function](http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2007/04/12/111504.aspx)

or

[Split XML style](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/22/60213.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. You can change this to use LIKE -

```
select top 1 sub_category 
  from sub_categories 
 where keywords like '%' + product_category + '%';
```

Comment: @Alessandro - I agree, Martin Smith's answer is better. I dint see that flaw in my answer.